# Hiding other toggles when a modal is activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, toggle

I have two modals, left and right, each drop down when clicked and want to have only one toggle appear as an on/off when activated.

Right now, both toggles appear when either modal is on. When the LEFT toggle is on and the modal drops down I want to hide the RIGHT toggle button and modal (and vice versa).

```js
// common close button
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".modal").toggleClass('modal-visible');
});

// explicit button per modal
$('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  var modalid = $(this).data("modal-id");
  $(`.modal[data-modal-id='${modalid}']`).toggleClass('modal-visible');
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  /* 1 */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal.modal-visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  background: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s height 0.5s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal.modal-visible .modal-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal-transition {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal.modal-visible .modal-transition {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-content {
  padding: 1em;
}

.modal-header {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.modal-close {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #aaa;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.modal-close:hover {
  color: #777;
}

.modal-heading {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.modal-content>*:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.modal-content>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal.modal-scroll .modal-content {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal.modal-scroll .modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  width: 32em;
  margin-left: -16em;
  background-color: #CDf;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  font-family: 'Republique', sans-serif;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0.5;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}

#righty {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 100000;
}

#lefty {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 100000;
}

body {
  background: pink;
}

button {
  color: white;
}

button:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="toggle" data-modal-id="lefty" id="lefty">LEFT</button>
<button class="toggle" data-modal-id="righty" id="righty">RIGHT</button>

<div class="modal" data-modal-id="lefty">
  <div class="modal-overlay toggle"></div>
  <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button class="modal-close toggle"></button>
      <h2 class="modal-heading">This is a modal on the left</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" data-modal-id="righty">
  <div class="modal-overlay toggle"></div>
  <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <h2 class="modal-heading">This is a modal on the right</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried various routes in CSS (nested divs, display:none, etc.) and struggling to find a solution. My javascript knowledge is very rudimentary, so perhaps there is a path there?

Answer (score 0):

I added 4 lines in your JS:

- We will declare 2 variables, one that will take the button's `id` (and therefore the modal `id` as well), and the other one, the `id` of the current visible modal.
- We will then check if the two `id` are **not** matching, if it is true (meaning the id aren't the same) then we hide the visible modal by removing its class `modal-visible`.
- If the two `id` are the same then we skip this step.
- Lastly, we will toggle the modal with the button's `id`, it will either close it or open it.

That's all.

```
// common close button
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".modal").toggleClass('modal-visible');
});

// explicit button per modal
$('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  var modalid = $(this).data("modal-id");
  var visible = $('.modal-visible').data("modal-id");
  //check if the IDs are not the same
  if (visible != modalid) {
          $('.modal-visible').removeClass('modal-visible'); 
  }
  $(`.modal[data-modal-id='${modalid}']`).toggleClass('modal-visible');
});
```

Comment: This works for the modal, but I also want to hide the button (LEFT or RIGHT) when the other is activated. Can this be added to the JS?

Comment: Sorry you edited your question so I did not code that part, however I am sure you can manage to make the buttons disappear as well with the code I gave you, as it is the same principle.